# Which is best to use Functional component or Class Component

Tags: react-bootstrap, react-component

In react project, which is best to use a functional component or a Class component

Comment: Earlier people used class based components because there was no concept of hooks so people could not use states in functional components. But now the only difference is boundary errors, you can refer to https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe a functional component is easier to use simply because of the state-management.

Using a class component means that you will have to manage your state as one object. Which quickly becomes messy for large React components.

When using a functional component, states are stored as constants which means that you  can access and manage them individually.

In the end its really just about which syntax you prefer.

More information can be found [here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/react-choose-functional-components)

Comment: Thanks for giving valuable feedback, and decided to use the functional component